# Use one select query instead of query + subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server 2014, data has been changed to protect the data. I hope the below makes sense.

I have to search a table for all categories with a Moderate risk. Then I need to go into another table (test) and retrieve those Moderate categories where only the Toby test has failed. Categories are unique in that first table.

So in the sample data below, categories 4 and 5 both are Moderate risk, and both also have Toby with a result of Fail in the test table.

However I want to exclude category 4 from my final output because that Category also has the Bill test that failed.

My goal is only to show Category 5 as an output. I can do this with a query and sub-query, where the sub-query returns categories 4 and 5, and the main query filters on that. But can I achieve the same thing with a single query somehow?

Update:

My current query is below. I've had to munge it a bit for this post, I hope it's sufficient. Basically the sub-query pulls in all categories that have any failed test for a Moderate category, and the main query filters out any categories with other failures.

```
select tt.category, tt.[name]
from test_table mt
where tt.category in (select mt.category
                      from main_table mt
                      inner join test_table tt on tt.category = mt.category
                      where mt.risk= 'Moderate' and tt.result = 'Fail')
  and tt.[name] <> 'Toby'
  and tt.[result] = 'Fail'
```

Output:

```
category    risk
----------------------
1           Minimal
2           Critical
3           Elevated
4           Moderate
5           Moderate


category    name    result
-------------------------------
1           Mark    Pass
1           Bill    No Result
1           John    Pass
1           Toby    Pass

2           Mark    Pass
2           Bill    No Result
2           John    Fail
2           Toby    Pass

3           Mark    Pass
3           Bill    No Result
3           John    Pass
3           Toby    Pass

4           Mark    Pass
4           Bill    Fail
4           John    Pass
4           Toby    Fail

5           Mark    Pass
5           Bill    Pass
5           John    Pass
5           Toby    Fail
```

Comment: Hello @THedge please do write your query. That would help a lot. Thanks!

Comment: *"I can do this with a query and sub-query"* showing you how to do this without a sub query would be far easier with said query you already have. We can't show you how to remove said sub query, if you don't show us what you already have,

Comment: @THedge Your example data does not have a Fail for Toby under category 5 as stated in your post. Might want to edit your sample data.

Comment: @Ryan, sorry, I have corrected the data. To the others, I will get my existing query up here asap.

Comment: Maybe this will help to others when they will try to help you: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9e63849b8dc445312e24380288ee6ee9

Comment: You could use an inner join but would that be better than using a subquery is questionable. Maybe you should share the code you already have.

Comment: It looks like the answer from forpas should work.  It would be nice to compare that to the original query that included a subquery.

Comment: @THedge your query has a small bug - first alias is mt and it should be tt. Also it returns some strange results to me ...

Comment: @VBoksic, yes I am sure you are correct, again I changed the query for the post so apologies for the error.
Thank you all for the help, I am going to try forpas's solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the tables, `group by category` and set the conditions in the HAVING clause:

```
select c.category
from categories c inner join test t
on c.category = t.category
where c.risk = 'Moderate'
group by c.category
having 
  sum(case when t.name = 'Toby' and t.result = 'Fail' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
  and 
  sum(case when t.name <> 'Toby' and t.result = 'Fail' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

or:

```
select c.category
from categories c inner join test t
on c.category = t.category
where c.risk = 'Moderate' and t.result = 'Fail'
group by c.category
having count(distinct t.name) = 1 and max(t.name) = 'Toby'
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e26bc364951aee93fb4fdf11b83f776f).
Results:

```
> | category |
> | -------: |
> |        5 |
```

Comment: No problem, I have deleted mine :)

Comment: Thank you very much forpas!! I will go with the first as it documents the business rule as well. That will help other developers if/when it must be modified in the future.

Answer (score 0):

A pretty direct reading of your question suggests `exists`/`not exists`:

```
select c.*
from categories c
where c.risk = 'Moderate' and
      exists (select 1
              from tests t
              where t.category = c.category and
                    t.name = 'Toby' and
                    t.result = 'Fail'
             ) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from tests t
                  where t.category = c.category and
                        t.name <> 'Toby' and
                        t.result = 'Fail'
                 );
```

Conditional aggregation is also a viable solution -- and a solution that I prefer when the filter is on only one table.  However, the filtering here is on two tables, and this will use of an index on `test(category, result, name)` and avoid the outer aggregation.

Comment: So instead of query+subquery you propose query+2 subqueries?

Comment: @forpas . . . Yes, I do.  That wasn't clear in the answer?  Each subquery is optimized to use the index, so this should be quite fast.

Comment: Read the title of the question: *Use one select query instead of query + subquery*